# Ant : Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details

Tags: java, linux, ant, javac

I want to run "ant build-project" a project build.xml.

```
    <javac deprecation="true"
           includeantruntime="false"
           debug="true"
           debuglevel="${debuglevel}"
           destdir="${project.build.outputpath}"
           verbose="true"
           encoding="UTF-8">
        <src path="${project.src.classes}" />
        <compilerarg value="-Xlint" />
        <classpath refid="core.classpath" />
    </javac>

<path id="core.classpath">          
   <pathelement location="${project.build.outputpath}" />       
      <pathelement location="${test.dir}" />
              <fileset dir="${project.build.libpath}">
                <include name="**/*.jar"/>
              </fileset>        
</path>
```

project.build.outputpath:/PROJECT_MAIN_DIR/target/classes
project.build.libpath:/PROJECT_MAIN_DIR/target/lib

But this output makes me crazy:

> build.xml:77: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for
>   details.  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:999)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:820)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)  at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:105)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:357)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:385)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1329)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1298)    at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1181)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:698)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:199)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:257)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:104)

My configuration:

**Ant:** Apache Ant version 1.7.0

**Java:** java version "1.6.0_24" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6
1.11.4) (6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.12.04.1) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)

**PC** ubuntu 12.04

```
XXX.java:248: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
    [javac]     private static void logNotFoundInMemory(Class entityClass, Integer id)
    [javac]                                             ^
    [javac]   missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
    [javac]   where T is a type-variable:
    [javac]     T extends Object declared in class Class


StatReporterJob.java:219: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
    [javac]             T stat = (T) snapshotRow[REFERENCE];
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   required: T
    [javac]   found:    Object
```

Would you help ?

Comment: this has nothing to do with ant, your classes can't be compiled for the reasons given by javac.

Comment: Don't you have any error. Those two are just warnings, caused by the -Xlint option. But AFAIK, they shouldn't cause the build to fail.

Comment: Ok.It seems causing about javac.But how can I fix it ?

Comment: Can you put the `core.classpath` here?